# ng-model doesn't work caused by scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-model doesn't work when it's inside  like this http://plnkr.co/edit/Sz5WqVJrk0lW6vLx0GDX?p=preview

I'm pretty sure there's no problem on the select syntax and my data.

Comment: For future reference, it would helpful if you posted the relevant code _inside_ the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your function as

```
$scope.selectFriend = function() {
    console.log(this.friendsModel.name);
};
```

since the `friendsModel` belongs to a child scope, not `$scope`.

Comment: so this here referring to the child itself?

Comment: @user3522457: right, `this` is referring to the child scope containing `friendsModel`

Answer (score 0):

It is a scoping issue. If you use the controller as syntax you will be able to quickly work around it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1xS3D4ZworwP7FmkzNjq